# Ignore only specific warnings in PHPUnit (like E_STRICT or E_DEPRECATED)

Tags: php, phpunit

How to tell PHPUnit to ignore only specific warnings thrown by old PHP code while running tests?

For example, how to ignore `E_DEPRECATED` and `E_STRICT` but leave PHPUnit to convert remaining warnings to exceptions?

Comment: You could turn off convertion errors to exceptions using this manual: http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Comment: Yes, but that will disable all Warnings / Errors.

Comment: You could define your own error handler using `set_error_handler`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPUnit has it's own error handler and it checks, if currently thrown error / warning has been disabled.

So the solution is to simply set error reporting level in the beginning of your app:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

And PHPUnit will not throw exceptions when these are encountered.

Comment: Personally I prefer `E_ALL ^ E_STRICT ^ E_DEPRECATED`. Maybe I'm just nerdy over XOR :D

Comment: In PHP 5.3 `E_ALL` does not include `E_STRICT`. 5.4 does. Therefore, XOR operator will give different output depending on the version you use.

Comment: You've got me there. Fair enough! (Although you'd think with a name like `E_ALL`, it would actually *mean* "all"!)